# Mac OS X 10.8 crashes after Thunderbolt display disconnect and sleep

Tags: macos, display, sleep-wake, crash, thunderbolt

At work I run my MacBook Pro 15" Retina (with Mac OS X 10.8.3 Snow Leopard) lid-closed with two Thunderbolt displays.

If I disconnect the power and displays, walk to a conference room, and re-open the lid, everything works as expected.

If I disconnect the power and displays, drive home, and re-open the lid after about an hour, the Mac crashes. The screen and keyboard light up but are unresponsive. The only way out is a long-press of the power key.

Any ideas how to diagnose or solve this?

**UPDATE 1** (per Bravado's question): There aren't any useful logs in /Library/Logs or ~/Library/Logs, but the syslog (via Console.app) contains a single interesting line amidst everything else which looks normal:

```
kernel[0]: DarkWake thermal limits breached. Going to sleep!
```

**UPDATE 2**: I remembered that a long time ago I had run `sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0` in an attempt to disable deep sleep which results in lengthy resumes. I've set it back to the default using `sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 3`... let's see if that helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in my update, I ran `sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 3` to reset the sleep mode and I've had only two of those crashes in the last six months.

FWIW, running two Thunderbolt displays on a lid-closed MacBook is hell. Now that I only use one Thunderbolt display, things are generally much more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look in ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/  if there are new entries that date from the crash?  Or look at the syslog (Utilities, Log-Viewer) if anything shows there prior to the hang?